# Another "why was my edit rejected?" question

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

As we know, link-only answers aren't very good. It's always better to take the (useful) info from the link and include it in the answer.

I did exactly that in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12521229), and I also removed a dead link. I also explained all of this in the "edit reason".

All three reviewers rejected the edit. Why?

Comment: What exactly did I write that was against what op wrote? I copied and pasted from the link

Comment: My guess: they saw [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TpOtz.png), said to themselves *Whoah that's a huge change*, and then rejected.

Comment: @Tunaki then they should have "skipped" that review instead of voting :P one should vote only if they are sure

Comment: You didn't look very hard for an alternative to the dead link. There is a copy here http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf. I've fixed the broken link.

Comment: 1. You removed one of the links of the answer (why?). 2. The text you copy and pasted removes the `(see Summary of Options)` link... which makes the text confusing (where is the summary of options?) 3. Copy + pasting text *verbatim* treads the line of plagiarism.

Comment: @Rob I explained why I removed the link

Comment: @Rob also it's not plagiarism, it's a very small portion, so it's fair use. As for the missing link, the reviewers had the possibility of improving my suggestion instead of rejecting it.

Comment: This is a four year old answer: you're better off spending your time editing any of the large number of more recent questions and answers that are horribly written.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan since when the age of a question started being relevant? I remember that SO's strong point was search engine traffic. I ended up on that question by following a google link, so it's very useful to improve that answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I would rather have people who need to have their edits reviewed (taking up other people's time) concentrate their edits on worthwhile changes. If you want to make edits like that, go right ahead, but your question was why it was rejected. There's a possible reason. You seem to be arguing against everyone's reasons here, which is less a [tag:discussion] than a chance for you to be right.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes that was my question, and you mentioned that that change wasn't worthwhile. I am not arguing against everyone's reasons here, DavidPostill made a good point on the second link (I could have found a mirror instead of deleting it), and that may have been a good reason to improve my edit. Yet I didn't see here a good argument for a rejection, by anyone.